# Missing Cloud Function User Agent role in Google Cloud IAM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-iam

I'm working on a series of Cloud Functions in one Google Cloud project and, for some reason, I suddenly get this error:

```
Deployment failure:
Missing necessary permission resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy for service-1092904037961@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com on resource projects/la-cloud-functions. Please grant service-1092904037961@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com the Cloud Functions Service Agent role. You can do that by running 'gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding projects/la-cloud-functions --member=service-1092904037961@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=Cloud Functions Service Agent'
```

Besides the badly formatted error response (you can't have `--role=Cloud Functions Service Agent` - it should be `--role=roles/cloudfunctions.serviceAgent`), when I try to run the amended command:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding projects/la-cloud-functions --member=service-1092904037961@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/cloudfunctions.serviceAgent
```

I get this error:

```
The requested URL <code>/v1/projects/la-cloud-functions/serviceAccounts/projects/la-cloud-functions:getIamPolicy?alt=json</code> was not found on this server.
```

Finally, trying to assign the Cloud Functions Server Agent role through the console gave me another surprise - the role is missing from the list, where it should be under Service Management:

[image]

I have tried to reset the service account by re-enabling the Cloud Functions API with this command:

`gcloud services enable cloudfunctions.googleapis.com`

But again, no success.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this problem and make the Cloud Functions Service Agent role available again?

TIA - Joe

Comment: If anyone else runs into this, I ran the service account creation script provided by John Hanley in his answer, but it didn't show up. Google added an "*Include Google-provided role grants*" checkbox top right of IAM page, click that and they appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following steps to solve this:

**Disable Cloud Functions API:**

```
gcloud services disable cloudfunctions.googleapis.com --project la-cloud-functions
```

Wait about a minute for the disable to complete.

**Delete the cloud functions member account using the CLI or using the GCP Console under IAM.**

```
gcloud projects remove-iam-policy-binding la-cloud-functions --member="serviceAccount:service-1092904037961@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/cloudfunctions.serviceAgent"
```

Wait about a minute. Then verify that this member has been removed in the GCP Console under IAM.

**Enable Cloud Functions API:**

```
gcloud services enable cloudfunctions.googleapis.com --project la-cloud-functions
```

**Go back to the GCP Console. You should find a new Google Cloud Functions Service Agent member.**

**Note:**

You are using the wrong command to add `cloudfunctions.serviceAgent`. Here is the correct command:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding la-cloud-functions --member="serviceAccount:service-1092904037961@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/cloudfunctions.serviceAgent"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, John for the complete answer. When I tried to disable the Cloud Functions member account via the shell, it said I needed to delete all my functions first. Rather than take that pretty drastic step if unnecessary, I used your revised command to add cloudfunctions.serviceAgent - that worked perfectly and I was able to run Cloud Build to deploy my function. I'm hoping that will fix any other issues, and if not, I'll go through the disable/enable process.

Comment: @JoeLowery - Glad to help. This IAM stuff can get complicated / confusing if you don't work with it every day.

Comment: Got the same issue, @JohnHanley your last command was enough in my case. Thanks!